# Im trying to make an astar algorithm for a school thing

Tags: sfml, a-star

Here is my code i've been working on. I've scraped off all the errors from the code. But i cant get the code to run correctly and the application either explodes or doesn't atleast visualise the astar.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

const int WIDTH = 10;
const int HEIGHT = 10;

struct Node
{
    int x;
    int y;
    mutable float gScore;
    mutable float fScore;
    mutable const Node* parent;

    Node(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y), gScore(0), fScore(0), parent(nullptr) {}

    bool operator==(const Node& other) const
    {
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }
};



// Hash function for nodes, needed for storing them in an unordered_map
struct NodeHash
{
    std::size_t operator()(const Node& node) const
    {
        return std::hash<int>()(node.x) ^ std::hash<int>()(node.y);
    }
};

// Overload the ">" operator for nodes, needed for using them in a priority queue
struct NodeGreater
{
    bool operator()(const Node& left, const Node& right) const
    {
        return left.fScore > right.fScore;
    }
};

// Represents a 2D grid
class Grid
{
public:
    Grid()
    {
        // Initialize the grid with all nodes as walkable
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                nodes[x][y] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the walkability of a node
    void setNode(int x, int y, bool walkable)
    {
        nodes[x][y] = walkable;
    }

    // Check if a node is walkable
    bool isNodeWalkable(int x, int y)
    {
        return nodes[x][y];
    }

private:
    bool nodes[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
};

// Calculate the Euclidean distance between two nodes
float euclideanDistance(Node a, Node b)
{
    int xDist = b.x - a.x;
    int yDist = b.y - a.y;
    return std::sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist);
}

// Estimate the cost of reaching the end node from a given node
float heuristicCostEstimate(Node start, Node end)
{
    return euclideanDistance(start, end);
}

// Get the neighbors of a given node
std::vector<Node> getNeighbors(Grid grid, Node node)
{
    std::vector<Node> neighbors;

    for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
        {
            // Skip the current node
            if (x == 0 && y == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            int neighborX = node.x + x;
            int neighborY = node.y + y;

            // Make sure the neighbor is within the bounds of the grid
            if (neighborX >= 0 && neighborX < WIDTH && neighborY >= 0 && neighborY < HEIGHT)
            {
                // Make sure the neighbor is walkable
                if (grid.isNodeWalkable(neighborX, neighborY))
                {
                    Node neighbor = { neighborX, neighborY };
                    neighbors.push_back(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return neighbors;
}

// Reconstruct the path from the end node to the start node
std::vector<Node> reconstructPath(Node end)
{
    std::vector<Node> path;
    Node current = end;

    while (current.parent != nullptr)
    {
        path.push_back(current);
        current = *current.parent;
    }

    path.push_back(current);
    std::reverse(path.begin(), path.end());

    return path;
}

// Run the A* algorithm to find the shortest path from the start to the end node
std::vector<Node> aStar(Grid grid, Node start, Node end)
{
    // Initialize the open and closed sets
    std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, NodeGreater> openSet;
    std::unordered_map<Node, bool, NodeHash> closedSet;

    // Add the start node to the open set
    openSet.push(start);

    // Set the starting node's gScore to 0 and fScore to the estimated cost to the end node
    start.gScore = 0;
    start.fScore = heuristicCostEstimate(start, end);

    // Keep searching until the open set is empty
    while (!openSet.empty())
    {

        // Get the node in the open set with the lowest fScore
        Node current = openSet.top();
        openSet.pop();

        // If the current node is the end node, we have found the shortest path
        if (current == end)
        {
            return reconstructPath(current);
        }

        // Add the current node to the closed set
        closedSet[current] = true;

        // Get the neighbors of the current node
        std::vector<Node> neighbors = getNeighbors(grid, current);

        // Iterate through the neighbors
        for (const Node& neighbor : neighbors)
        {
            // Skip the neighbor if it is already in the closed set
            if (closedSet.count(neighbor) > 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Calculate the tentative gScore for the neighbor
            float tentativeGScore = current.gScore + euclideanDistance(current, neighbor);

            bool neighborIsBetter = false;
            bool neighborInOpenSet = false;
            // Check if the neighbor is already in the open set
            std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, NodeGreater> tempOpenSet = openSet;
            while (!tempOpenSet.empty())
            {
                Node tempNeighbor = tempOpenSet.top();
                tempOpenSet.pop();
                if (tempNeighbor == neighbor)
                {
                    neighborInOpenSet = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Update the neighbor's scores and parent if the tentative gScore is lower than
            if (tentativeGScore < neighbor.gScore)
            {
                neighborIsBetter = true;
                neighbor.gScore = tentativeGScore;
                neighbor.fScore = tentativeGScore + heuristicCostEstimate(neighbor, end);
            }

            if (!neighborInOpenSet || neighborIsBetter)
            {
                // Update the neighbor's parent to the current node
                neighbor.parent = &current;

                // Add the neighbor to the open set if it is not already there
                if (!neighborInOpenSet)
                {
                    openSet.push(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If we reach here, it means that we have not found a path to the end node
    return std::vector<Node>();
}


int main()
{
    // Create the window and grid
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "A*");
    Grid grid;

    // Set some nodes as unwalkable
    grid.setNode(3, 3, false);
    grid.setNode(3, 4, false);
    grid.setNode(3, 5, false);
    grid.setNode(4, 3, false);
    // Set the start and end nodes
    Node start = { 1, 1 };
    Node end = { 8, 8 };

    // Run the A* algorithm and get the path
    std::vector<Node> path = aStar(grid, start, end);

    // Main loop
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();

        // Draw the grid
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(50, 50));
                rect.setPosition(x * 50, y * 50);
                if (grid.isNodeWalkable(x, y))
                {
                    rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
                }
                else
                {
                    rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
                }
                window.draw(rect);
            }
        }

        // Draw the path
        for (Node node : path)
        {
            sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(50, 50));
            rect.setPosition(node.x * 50, node.y * 50);
            rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
            window.draw(rect);
        }

        // Draw the start and end nodes
        sf::RectangleShape startRect(sf::Vector2f(50, 50));
        startRect.setPosition(start.x * 50, start.y * 50);
        startRect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        window.draw(startRect);

        sf::RectangleShape endRect(sf::Vector2f(50, 50));
        endRect.setPosition(end.x * 50, end.y * 50);
        endRect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        window.draw(endRect);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

any idea why its doing this?

I've tried to debug the code and i cant seem to find the problem. Either the code doesn't run or it just shows the same thing